# Working with Large Fixed Length Files in R using ff

Tags: r, ff

I did some research and the ff package seems to have what I am looking for. However, I have no idea how to use it in my current scenario. Here's what I got:

- I have a fixed length file with no row terminator (all data in one line)
- Record length is 1577 with 55 columns
- Total records in file based on record length is >9 million

as you can imagine processing this file through R normally would destroy my RAM. How would I go about loading a file like this?

Below is the the code i use to handle smaller files that are capable of being loaded into RAM. This freezes my machine on larger files:

`conn <- file(fileName,'r')`
`data <- readChar(conn,rep(widths,TotalRecords))`
`df <- data.frame(matrix(data,ncol=nFields,byrow=TRUE))`

Comment: Have you considered opening a streaming connection and using `readChar` to pass chunks to `read.fwf` which you then write in blocks with `write.ff`? I ask because I do not see a fwf-read function in the methods listed in the Index of the ff-package.

Comment: I wasn't aware that read.fwf was capable of handling a file with no row terminator. I haven't had any success with that. Im also afraid i wouldn't know the first thing about passing chunks. I had thought of the idea but i didn't know where to start.

Comment: Which character is separating the records?

Comment: There is none, the record simply ends after a specific number of characters. In this case at 1577, at 1578 the next record starts until another 1577 is read and so on until EOF.

Comment: I was thinking you would break the stream with `readChar` into the proper length chunks for `read.fwf` perhaps 1000 lines at a time.